# How to validate input file type onclick submit using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

In this code I simply want to validate `pancard_img`. What happens right now if pancard image not empty then it again shows me 'Pancard image should not be empty. If `pancard_img` have a value. How can I fix this one?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (("#pancard").val() == '') {
      $("#err_pan").html("Pancard should not be empty");
    } else if (("#pancard_img").val() == '') {
      $("#err_pan_img").html("Pancard image should not be empty");
    } else {
      alert("successful");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="pancard" id="pancard" />
  <div id="err_pan"></div>
  <input type="file" name="pancard_img" id="pancard_img" value="Pan1.png" />
  <div id="err_pan_img"></div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: `echo` is a PHP keyword, not JS. It's causing an error which is likely resulting in the validation not working.

Comment: As a comment to Rory what you most likely want is `alert("successful")`

Answer (score 0):

There are few Syntactical mistakes in your code like,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#pancard").val() == '') { // add $
      $("#err_pan").html("Pancard image should not be empty");
    } else if($("#pancard_img").val() == '') { // add $
      $("#err_pan_img").html("Pancard image should not be empty");
    } else {
      alert("successful"); // You can use alert, echo is for php
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Actually, I am getting dynamic value inside the `pancard_img` but still it show me `not empty message` @DharaParmar

Answer (score 0):

Remove the echo from the submit handler and move the `e.preventDefault()` inside the conditions, so that it doesn't block the form from submitting, when the input has value.
Also you forgot to use `$` when selecting the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    if ($("#pancard").val() == '') {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#err_pan").html("Pancard image should not be empty");
    } else if ($("#pancard_img").val() == '') {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#err_pan_img").html("Pancard image should not be empty");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="pancard" id="pancard" />
  <div id="err_pan"></div>
  <input type="file" name="pancard_img" id="pancard_img" value="Pan1.png" />
  <div id="err_pan_img"></div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```